# High CPU usage from SQLServer process

Tags: sql-server

I have a VPS with Windows Server 2012 R2 and there are 5 running websites using SQL Server 2012 express. I notices extremely high CPU Usage caused by process called htjl.exe. I found this file in C:\ProgramData\TMP folder. I tried to delete it but it was created again. When I go to details I see this and it seems that it is something related to SQLServer.

[image]

Can you tell me what is this process and how I can stop it to consume so many CPU?

Comment: Sounds a bit fishy, zero google hits & HTJL is a mash-the-keyboard type name like QWER.  Are you spawning a process in T-SQL via xp_cmdshell?  Have you run a virus scan? - If I saw this I would consider the possibility of  something being compromised.

Comment: No, it just a VPS running several websites. I haven't even logged in for weeks. I haven't run a virus scan, but I'll do it. If it is a virus how is it possible to catch it when nobody is doing nothing on this server?

Comment: For example if you had an SQL Injection vulnerability in your site code and XPs were enabled I could perhaps upload an executable, write it to disk and run it.  I could pick and name for it and it would run as the SQL Service user as per your pic.

Comment: What tool is that image snapshot from?  What is the central column (with SYSYEM and MSSQLSERVER in it) supposed to be?

Comment: Hmm, this might be associated with the old HijackThis logger.

Comment: But it does really look like a virus/worm at this point, so I'd recommend treating it as such.

Comment: Quick fix: Delete it and then copy some other EXE that won't do anything in this context in with the same name.

Comment: the screenshot is fromTask Manager - the column name is User name